# How to compare time from existing records in rails 4 and mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Lets say, a user already has a task in database. Task's attributes are `week_day: 'Monday', start_at: '12:30', ends_at: '13:30'` than new task should not be assigned to same user at that time duration. How do i achieve this. i would appreciate any help :)

```
class User
  has_many :tasks
end

class task
  belongs_to :user
  field :week_day,  type: String    # e.g 'Monday'
  field :starts_at, type: String    # e.g '13:00'
  field :ends_at,   type: String    # e.g '13:30'
  field :user_id
end
```

Comment: Can you change the schema so that the values are numbers? You should be able to kludge around `starts_at` and `ends_at` as they are (assuming that they're always in 24 hour time) but `week_day` really should be a number.

Comment: by the way, i m using symbol in week_day anyways, lets change as u say but how do we validate it via before_save callback

Comment: can u give me a hint

Comment: Never mind the `week_day` issue, I misunderstood. You have a specific date in mind, right?

Comment: Task repeats every week and doesn't save specific date that's why i keep start_at and ends_at as string. i can show them in view by Time.parse(task.starts_at).strftime("%h:%M")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the intervals don't cross day boundaries so you don't have to worry about that. The presence of a separate day of week field sort of implies this.

You'll need to have validations to ensure that both `starts_at` and `ends_at` exist and have the right format. You'll also need to ensure that `starts_at` is strictly less than `ends_at` so that your times make sense.

Luckily your `HH:MM` format compares properly (i.e. `'11:02' < '13:42'` as strings) so we can use simple string operators to compare times.

That leaves overlaps. Given two open intervals, `(a, b)` and `(c, d)`, how can they overlap? A couple simple diagrams should help:

```
(a----b)-----     (1)
----(c-----d)

----(a-----b)     (2)
(c----d)-----

(a---------b)     (3)
---(c--d)----

---(a--b)----     (4)
(c---------d)
```

We also have variants of the above where `a == c` or `b == d` but we don't have to treat those specially, we can just use inclusive inequality tests.

**1** and **3** can be taken care of with a simple `a <= c <= b` check, **2** and **4** can be taken care of by checking `c <= a <= d`.

If we call the new interval `(a, b)` then we want to make sure that there aren't any `(c, d)` intervals in the database for that person on that day that satisfy those above inequalities. Translating into Mongoid we have:

```
# This user's tasks on the day we care about.
base = class.where(:user_id => user_id, :week_day => week_day)

if(base.where(:starts_at.gte => starts_at, :starts_at.lte => ends_at).exists?)
  # Overlap because a <= c <= b, report an error.
elsif(base.where(:starts_at.lte => starts_at, :ends_at.gte => starts_at).exists?)
  # Overlap because c <= a <= d, report an error.
end
```

This is, of course, subject to race conditions just like all client-side validations. If you want to be really safe, you'd have to push the logic into the database using some sort of unique index and you'd probably have to store your time intervals in a different format to satisfy MongoDB's limited capabilities.